# ActiveMQ Artemis Jolokia returns Status "404"

Tags: activemq-artemis, jolokia

I want to get the amount of messages I have in my ActiveMQ Artemis queue, but when I execute this command:

```
curl -v -H "Origin:http://IP:port" -u user:pass http://IP:Port/console/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=0.0.0.0,component=addresses,address=123456,subcomponent=queues,routing-type=anycast,queue=123456/MessageCount
```

I get this error

```
"error":"javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException : org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=0.0.0.0,component=addresses,address=123456,subcomponent=queues,routing-type=anycast,queue=123456","status":404
```

Do you know why? If I put this URL

```
http://IP:Port/console/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=0.0.0.0,component=addresses,address=123456,subcomponent=queues,routing-type=anycast,queue=123456/MessageCount
```

in a browser like Chrome it works but with `curl` it doesn't work.

Comment: The browser may be providing additional headers that your `curl` call is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of an queue's MBean follows this pattern:

```
org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker="brokerName",component=addresses,address="addressName",subcomponent=queues,routing-type="routingType",queue="queueName"
```

Note that the **quotation marks** are part of the MBean's name. Therefore you need to specify them in your `curl` command. Here's an example that works for me with the default broker:

```
curl -v -H "Origin: http://localhost" -u myUser:myPass http://localhost:8161/console/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"0.0.0.0\",component=addresses,address=\"DLQ\",subcomponent=queues,routing-type=\"anycast\",queue=\"DLQ\"/MessageCount
```

Notice the quotation marks along with the proper escaping so it executes on the command-line. There is a similar (although simpler) example in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html#exposing-jmx-using-jolokia).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the problem